# JPA predicate criteriabuilder many to many trouble

Tags: java, spring, jpa, predicate

I have 3 tables like `alarm`, `alarmTag` and `alarm_alarmTag`. `alarm` and `alarmTag` table have ManyToMany relation. `alarm_alarmTag` table is mapping `alarm` and `alarmTag` tables.

Each alarm can have many alarm tags. For example `alarm1` has `tag1` and `tag2`. So I want to create a search filter which when I select `tag1` on that filter, I want to display alarms which have `tag1`.

I have done this with join but the problem is when I filter for `tag1` it shows only `tag1` on the tag column but there are other tags on that column.

**before filter:**

```
+------------------+
|     alarm table  |
+------------------+
| id  | tag        |
+------------------+
| 1   | tag1, tag2 | 
| 2   | tag3, tag4 |
+------------------+
```

**after filter with `tag1`:**

```
+------------------+
|     alarm table  |
+------------------+
| id  |    tag     |
+------------------+
| 1   |    tag1    |(this column must also have `tag2`)
+------------------+
```

**model:**

```java
public class ActiveAlarm {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private Set<AlarmTag> alarmTag;

}
```

**controller:**

```java
@GetMapping("/active")
public List<ActiveAlarmView> findAll(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "") List<Long> alarmTag) {

    var data = repository.findAll(ActiveAlarmSpecification.filter(alarmTag));

    return data.stream().map(record -> ActiveAlarmView.builder()
        .id(record.getId())            
        .alarmTag(record.getAlarmTag()))
        .build()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**filter Specification:**

```java
public class ActiveAlarmSpecification {

  /**
   * Filter Specification.
   */
  public static Specification<ActiveAlarm> filter(List<Long> alarmTag) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
      query.distinct(true);

      ArrayList<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

      if (!alarmTag.isEmpty()) {
        //***problem is in this line***
        predicates.add(root.join("alarmTag").get("id").in(alarmTag));
      }

      return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    };
  }
}
```

**alarmTag model:**

```java
public class AlarmTag {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String label;
}
```

And this is my request link: `http://localhost:8080/api/test/v1/alarm/active?alarmTag=1`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to fetch those separately or use `group by` to aggregate tag names/ids (and use DTO for projection unfortunately).

The reason behind this is that is exactly what SQL will produce. Query will be +- like:

```
SELECT * FROM alarm a JOIN alarm_tag at ON ... JOIN tag t ON ... WHERE t.id IN (your,tags)
```

When you have only single tag, this query rsult will not include any other tags that are that have different id than in `IN` clause

You will get all the alarms you want, but tags are filtered from the result - and this is exaclty what you are seeing here

You can try to replace `root.join` with `root.fetch` or try additional `root.fetch` aside, but I am not sure if either will work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by filtering data in controller with `Collections.disjoint`. I don't use criteria builder so I removed `filter Specification`. But I want to use criteria builder so if anyone can find a solution please post it.

Here is the solution:

```
@GetMapping("/active")
public List<ActiveAlarmView> findAll(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "") 
List<Long> alarmTag) {

    return data.stream().filter(r -> !alarmTag.isEmpty() ? !disjoint(r.getAlarmTag().stream().map(x -> x.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList()), alarmTag) : true)
        .map(record -> ActiveAlarmView.builder()
        .id(record.getId())            
        .alarmTag(record.getAlarmTag()))
        .build()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```